# Django-bootstrap-modal-forms on datatable row click

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

So, I have datatable, and I need to open modal form whenever a row is clicked.

My table is defined like this

```html
<table id="tabledata" class="datatable display">
```

Using [django-bootstrap-modal-forms](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms), I've done this:

```
$('.datatable').modalForm({
    formURL: "{% url 'myapp:modelform-url' %}"
}).on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
    // other code here
})
```

It sort of works, except the modal pops up wherever I click on the table.

I tried something like this but doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.tabledata tbody tr').modalForm({})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out and apparently this works:

```
$('.datatable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
    $('.datatable tbody').modalForm({
        formURL : "{% url 'here' %}"
    )}
})
```